# django forms multiple form with one field same by default

Tags: django, forms

I have a list of links,(A,B,C,D,) each link opens the same pop up form with fields (name , email, region, service)
all the inputs except SERVICE is user input.
I want the service field to have a default name of the links.

```
EXAMPLE: 

LINK A

---FORM-------

NAME= .........

EMAIL=........

REGION=........

SERVICE=FORM A

===========================

LINK B

---FORM-------

NAME= .........

EMAIL=........

REGION=........

SERVICE=FORM B
```

====================================

I want the service field to have that default value. 
how can I achieve that in Django??????

Comment: Here you can create a base form having fields name, email and region. And then create 4 different forms inherited from the base form with an additional field 'service' and then send these 4 forms in context to html.

Comment: thanks ankita, the idea of subclasses is good, how would I go about creating a view for it???? I want all the forms to be in the same template as those link cos I'm creating a pop up form. and the data enter by the user will be emailed.

Comment: yes you have to create a view for it..and then only you can send all forms in context to template.

Comment: thanks again ankita. I'm new to Django, I know to create a view, will all these forms be in the same view or I need to create view for each form?? and if its multiple views then how do I send all the forms in single template.. can u please show me an example? can I give u my email and ill show u my source code????

Comment: Hi san.I have added a piece of code in the answer.You can refer it and if you have issues then you can share your email with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create base form and other forms in your forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    region = forms.CharField(label="Region")

class AForm(BaseForm):
    service = forms.CharField(initial="A")

class BForm(BaseForm):
    service = forms.CharField(initial="B")

class CForm(BaseForm):
    service = forms.CharField(initial="C")

class DForm(BaseForm):
    service = forms.CharField(initial="D")
```

Now in your view you can add forms as below:

```
def example_view(request):
    context = {
        'aform':AForm(),
        'bform':BForm(),
        'cform':CForm(),
        'dform':DForm()
    }
    template = "xyz.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Now in your 'xyz.html' you can access these forms using context variables: aform, bform, cform, dform.

Comment: let us [continue the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160805/discussion-between-ankita-and-san).

Comment: click on the link above (continue the discussion in chat) and you will be redirected to chat room

Comment: ok .I saw the mail but I could not get what the error or problem you are facing. will you please share me your errors or problem.

Comment: I guess the answer is clear and justifying what you have asked, why don't you refer the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) for more information. and post another question with specific issue if any, avoid asking questions in comments section.

Comment: thanks satendra, ive tried the official documentation, its not written in the simplest form to understand it in one shot. that's y I'm asking help from you experienced .